# How to groupby continous records (e.g., "gaps and islands") in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My problems is the same as, [How to group by continuous records in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62055274/how-to-group-by-continuous-records-in-sql), only I need a solution in Pandas.

Given a df like

```
ID  Colour
------------
 1   Red
 2   Red
 3   Red
 4   Red
 5   Red
 6   Green
 7   Green
 8   Green
 9   Green
10   Red
11   Red
12   Red
13   Red
14   Green
15   Green
16   Green
17   Blue
18   Blue
19   Red
20   Blue
```

I want it grouped into

```
color  minId
------------
Red     1
Green   6
Red    10
Green  14
Blue   17
Red    19
Blue   20
```

It is okay to change the name of the colors (e.g., `Green1`)

The solution should generalize into other aggregations other than just `min`

Comment: I think not correct dupe, so reopened.

Comment: @jezrael how is it not the same as [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/how-to-groupby-consecutive-values-in-pandas-dataframe)? `(df.a != df.a.shift()).cumsum()`

Comment: @mozway - aggregation min and first?

Comment: @mozway - part dupe, agree, total dupe, not

Comment: Given the title I think the aggregation doesn't really matter here, it's just an example. Anyway do as you want, but please if you reopen leave the duplicate link. It's a bit annoying to search for existing answer to have this work just dropped from a single click. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grouping by consecutive values by helper Series created by compared shifted values and `cumsum` and then aggregate `first` and `min`:

```
g = df['Colour'].ne(df['Colour'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(g).agg(color=('Colour','first'), minId=('ID','min')).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   color  minId
0    Red      1
1  Green      6
2    Red     10
3  Green     14
4   Blue     17
5    Red     19
6   Blue     20
```

Comment: Works great. For people who prefer chained statements, this can be reworked into `df.assign(g = lambda x: x.Colour.ne(x.Colour.shift()).cumsum()).groupby('g').agg(color=('Colour','first'), minId=('ID','min'))`

Comment: Hello everyone! In case I have multiple columns, what's the approach?